# Why define a macro to a function with the same name?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I found the code below in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h

```
static __always_inline bool arch_atomic_sub_and_test(int i, atomic_t *v)
{
        return GEN_BINARY_RMWcc(LOCK_PREFIX "subl", v->counter, e, "er", i);
}
#define arch_atomic_sub_and_test arch_atomic_sub_and_test
```

what does the `#define` really do? When is it necessary to do so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sometimes some architectures in the Linux kernel don't provide certain functions, such as `arch_atomic_sub_and_test`. This allows these functions to be conditionally provided without breaking other architectures.

The `#define` allows you to test for the existence of the function with `#ifdef`:

```
#ifdef arch_atomic_sub_and_test
// use arch_atomic_sub_and_test
#else
// some other equivalent code
#endif
```

or it can be used to error out if the function is not available:

```
#ifndef arch_atomic_sub_and_test
# error "arch_atomic_sub_and_test not available"
#endif
```

For example, this is how it's used in the Linux kernel (from `include/asm-generic/atomic-instrumented.h`):

```
#if defined(arch_atomic_sub_and_test)
static inline bool
atomic_sub_and_test(int i, atomic_t *v)
{
        kasan_check_write(v, sizeof(*v));
        return arch_atomic_sub_and_test(i, v);
}
#define atomic_sub_and_test atomic_sub_and_test
#endif
```