# How to set defines with the same name as a function in c /c++?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I have a not very well documented c library which allows me to override some functions. But sadly there are no examples :(

library.h:

```
#ifndef some_function
uint8_t some_function(void);
#endif
```

So I defined a function like this in my c++ code:

```
#include "library.h"

extern "C" uint8_t some_function(void) { return 0;}

void main() {
....
}
```

but it uses the code define in the library.

Next try:

```
#define some_function
#include "library.h"

uint8_t some_function(void) { return 0;}
```

results in:

```
src/main.cpp: error: expected unqualified-id before 'void'
 extern "C" uint8_t some_function(void);
```

because function name is replaced by the define.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need that? Are you just curious, or are you chasing a XY problem?

Comment: It's implemented that way in a library I have to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any suggestions?

```cpp
#define some_function some_function
```

Not advocating for this, of course, but it should work.

Maybe the author wanted to allow the users to define their own functions with different names. I.e. the macro is not meant as much for you, as for the library to use a custom function name.

```cpp
uint8_t my_function(void) { return 0;}

...

#define some_function my_function
#include "library.h"
```

If no one defined such macro, the author defined a function with the same so all the calls would work.

Comment: It will work. It makes the token available to the pre-processor too. I've seen it used in the other direction however (to the OP), where it serves as a sort of feature test macro for the function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59267835/why-define-a-macro-to-a-function-with-the-same-name

Comment: After I made define in the CMakefile it worked. Just adding the define to the main.cpp wasn't enought.

Comment: @Steve That might happen if the library is itself a CMake project, or if it is included in multiple translation units. CMake is the right place to put these project-wide macros.